# Jquery carousel clicking active item doesnt redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I've got a carousel in this webpage https://stfn.herokuapp.com and It works almost perfect, only the main (active) item, which is in the center, Doesn't do anything once it's clicked (it's supposed to redirect) I tried to add the link both in js file and in the index, but didn't solve the problem anyone got tips?

[edit]

Forgot to upload the latest build before asking the question, just did it. So I added an a tag to the img in the index.html, and that doesn't seem to work either. Here's a snippet of code for redirecting from the js file

```
    $('.carousel .item').click(function(e) {
        var index = $(this).index('li');
        carousel.cycleActiveTo(index);
        // song3();
        e.preventDefault();

        if ( currentIndex != index ){
            var difference;

            if ( currentIndex == 0 && index >= 5 ){
                difference = (index - currentIndex) - 13;
            } else {
                difference = index - currentIndex;
            }

            difference = Math.abs(difference);
            delay = difference * options.duration;
            currentIndex = index;

            console.log(delay);

            setTimeout( goToLink, delay );
        }
    });

    goToLink = function() {
        if (currentIndex == 0) {
            // console.log("works:");
            document.location.href = "about.html"
        }
        if (currentIndex == 1) {
            document.location.href = "blog.html"
        }
        else if (currentIndex == 2) {
            document.location.href = "collection.html"
        }
        else if (currentIndex == 3) {
            document.location.href = "shop.html"
        }
        else if (currentIndex == 4) {
            // alert("ABOUT2");
            document.location.href = "about.html"
        }
        else if (currentIndex == 5) {
            document.location.href = "blog.html"
        }
        else if (currentIndex == 6) {
            document.location.href = "collection.html"
        }
        else if (currentIndex == 7) {
            document.location.href = "contact.html"
        }
        else if (currentIndex == 8) {
            document.location.href = "shop.html"
        }
        else if (currentIndex == 9) {
            document.location.href = "contact.html"
        }
        else if (currentIndex == 0) {
            document.location.href = "about.html"
        }
    }

});
```

So as you see, every element has an index assigned to it, and it allows to switch to a specific page. The active item has the index number 0, however it doesn't seem to work like the others

Comment: show some code. And of course it doesn't do anything. that `img` doesn't have any links on it.

Comment: oh, forgot to upload the latest build. also added the code that's responsible for redirecting

Comment: That `goToLink` fn is terrible. :D put the links/pages in array and call `document.location.href = linkArray[currentIndex]`

Comment: Thanks! I'm feeling the baltic love from your side haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ( currentIndex != index ){` <-- this check is false since both are zero.

So if the check is equal it does nothing

You need an else and call the goto method.

```
if ( currentIndex != index ){ 
   ... the code ...
} else {
    goToLink();
}
```